# Watch Face Format XML: Complication slot has only the "Empty" option

Tags: wear-os, watch-face-api

When creating a watch face with the Watch Face Format XML, the complication has only the "Empty" slot option available on the Watch app on the mobile phone. On the smartwatch, all available options are shown.

Did anyone else notice the same problem? Is there a known issue with the Wear app (although, other watch faces show complications options properly), or is there a problem in my XML definition (please see the XML below)?

Complication options missing in the Wear app on the smartphone:
[image: Complication options missing in the Wear app on the smartphone]

Complication options are properly displayed on the smartwatch:
[image: Complication options are properly displayed on the smartwatch]

The XML definition of the complication slot:

```
            <ComplicationSlot
            x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100"
            slotId="10"
            supportedTypes="SHORT_TEXT"
            isCustomizable="TRUE">
            <BoundingOval x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
            <DefaultProviderPolicy defaultSystemProvider="WATCH_BATTERY" defaultSystemProviderType="SHORT_TEXT" />
            <Complication type="SHORT_TEXT">
                <PartImage x="35" y="16" width="22" height="22" pivotX="0.5" pivotY="0.5" alpha="255">
                    <Image resource="[COMPLICATION.MONOCHROMATIC_IMAGE]"/>
                </PartImage>
                <PartText x="18" y="39" width="56" height="22" pivotX="0.5" pivotY="0.5" alpha="255">
                    <Text align="CENTER" ellipsis="TRUE">
                        <Font family="SYNC_TO_DEVICE" size="20" weight="NORMAL"
                            slant="NORMAL" color="#ffffffff">
                            <Template>
                                %s
                                <Parameter expression="[COMPLICATION.TEXT]"/>
                            </Template>
                        </Font>
                    </Text>
                </PartText>
                <PartText x="19" y="62" width="54" height="14" pivotX="0.5" pivotY="0.5" alpha="255">
                    <Text align="CENTER" ellipsis="TRUE">
                        <Font family="SYNC_TO_DEVICE" size="12" weight="NORMAL"
                            slant="NORMAL" color="#ffadadad">
                            <Template>
                                %s
                                <Parameter expression="[COMPLICATION.TITLE]"/>
                            </Template>
                        </Font>
                    </Text>
                </PartText>
            </Complication>
        </ComplicationSlot>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@amoletwatchfaces, yes, it seems you are right.

An issue has been opened at Google's issue tracker today:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/306202747?pli=1

> This is a known issue and should be fixed in an upcoming release of the companion app, currently planned for November.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the Pixel Watch companion app issue. Customization works fine on Emulator and also on physical Pixel Watch 1/2.